# How to get a callback for all UIViewControllers ViewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift

I am using swizzling to call a method when every `UIViewController` appears on screen.

Code:

```
extension UIViewController {

    open override class func initialize() {

        guard self === UIViewController.self else { return }

        let originalSelector = #selector(self.viewWillAppear(_:))
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(self.proj_viewWillAppear(animated:))
        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }

    func proj_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.proj_viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
        let viewControllerName = NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
        print("viewWillAppear: \(viewControllerName)")
    }
}
```

but i'm getting a warning:

> Method 'initialize() defines Objective-C class method 'initialize', which is not guaranteed to be invoked by Swift and will be disallowed in future versions

is there a different way to get the same result?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you really need the swizzling?

Comment: According to me the best practise to achieve it is inherit all your viewControllers with a baseViewController, and then do your need full work in viewWillAppear of baseViewController. No need to call any method.

Comment: My first option was to use inheritance.
But i think for my case this is better.

I have a few services that i want to register to all VIewController lifeCycle.

Comment: For a global change, I think swizzling is the only way possible. As objective-c will continue a long time, I think you can make these dynamic things in .m file, which is sure to work and not any warnings at all.